# How to calculate FPS on device level in android

Tags: android

Anyone having any idea about how to get FPS(frame per second) of android device ?

There is an option in development settings to display FPS, but I want to write an app to do the same.

It internally calls `surfaceflinger` api.

Answer (score 5):

In your main `Activity` class override the `onDraw()` method. Invoke `super.onDraw()` then store the current system time. Calculate the `delta_time` in ms between the current call to draw and the previous call to draw.  Then calculate FPS using `1000 ms / delta_time ~ FPS`

Here is some pseudocode:

```
void onDraw(){
  super.onDraw()
  curTime = getTime();
  deltaTime = curTime - prevTime();
  aproxFps = 1000 / deltaTime;
  prevTime = curTime;
}
```

Comment: But this will calculate the FPS of the application only not the FPS of the device, right?

Comment: Using the standard android API's you cannot get the framerate of the device. You'll need to use `root` or roll your own custom rom.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't something you can do unless you root the device and get under the hood somehow.